# Usage for global.jelly and config.jelly in Jenkins plugin

Tags: jenkins-plugins, jelly

I am working on a Jenkins plugin using Maven 3 see two default .jelly files: global.jelly and config.jelly. What is the difference between the two, and can you give me examples of what goes in each file?

This is a result of a project created by:

```
mvn hpi:create
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- global.jelly is for global configuration (i.e per Jenkins instance - the values you can configure at `http://<your_jenkins_server>/configure` ) 
  examples can be - SMTP server address  if this is a mailer plugin,  or some tool location if your plugin calls that tool
- config.jelly is for the job configuration - defining plugin parameters for a specific job.

examples: mail recipients for that job reports, specific execution parameters, output file locations, etc.