# what is global configuration in jenkins plugins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have been going through jenkins manual but I could not understand the difference between using config.jelly (local configuration) and global.jelly (global configuration). Is it like if I update the global configuration of plugin, is it going to update all the instances of that plugin? So **basically what is the impact when someone changes the global configuration**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as explained on this post:
[Usage for global.jelly and config.jelly in Jenkins plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24535459/usage-for-global-jelly-and-config-jelly-in-jenkins-plugin)

- global.jelly is for global configuration
- config.jelly is for the job configuration

The setting are different, and have a different impact.

Any change made on global.jelly should impact all the job. But each change made on config.jelly should impact only the current job.

If you need to define where you want to put your setting, you need to ask yourself if you want it job specific or common to all your job.

For example you might want to tune the list of recipient for your report, and put it in your config.jelly.
But you want to centralize the settings for your mail server (easier to maintain) and then decide to put it in global.jelly